# Setting Background Color on Kendo Combobox Wipes Out Bindings

Tags: jquery, css, mvvm, kendo-ui

We're trying to set the background color on a Kendo combobox. However, setting the color appears to also wipe out the data bindings. In the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeeMellinger/fmovrgso/4/) example below the background of the second combobox (cb2) is set but has no items.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeeMellinger/fmovrgso/4/)

```
<div id="example">
    <input id="cb1" class="combobox" />
    <input id="cb2" class="combobox" />
    <input id="cb3" class="combobox" />
</div>


var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    allowCustomValues: false,
    testData: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'BMW'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Audi'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Ferrari'
        }]
    })
});

$('.combobox').kendoComboBox({
    dataSource: viewModel.testData,
    autoBind: false,
    dataTextField: 'name',
    dataValueField: 'id',
    suggest: true,
    placeholder: 'Select a car'
});

kendo.bind('#example', viewModel);

// ******************************************
// SET BACKGROUND COLOR
// ******************************************
var cb = $("#cb2").kendoComboBox().data("kendoComboBox");
cb.wrapper.find(".k-input").css("background", "#FFFFE0");

//ddl.input.css("background", propertyValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var cb = $("#cb2").kendoComboBox().data("kendoComboBox");
```

to this:

```
var cb = $("#cb2").data("kendoComboBox");
```

Including .kendoComboBox() is causing the ComboBox to be re-initialised (to some extent), causing the issue you observe. The selection #cb2 has already been instantiated as a ComboBox so there is no need to invoke the method again.